# Unique solution of quadratic expression

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, quadratics

I have a quadratic expression: $x^HAx - B$ in which I have to solve for $x$. $A$ is a 4 x 4 positive definite hermitian matrix and $x$ is a 4 x 1 vector. I have solved it by considering Singular Value Decomposition of A as well as Cholesky decomposition of A but each time I have obtained a different solution for this expression. Is it possible to obtain $x$ such that $x^HAx = B$ (or close) for this problem? I would appreciate suggestions.

Comment: $B$ is a positive real number? why should $x$ be unique? this cant be expectted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to find $x$ such that $x^HAx = B$, where $B \geq 0$ is a real number. Let $v_1, \ldots, v_4$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$ with $Av_i = \lambda_i v_i$. Write $x = a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_4 v_4$. Then you have

$$ x^HAx = \left< Ax, x \right> = \sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i |a_i|^2 = B. $$

This gives you all possible solutions. If you work over the real numbers, you can see that the set of all solutions is an [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and in particular, the solutions are definitely not unique.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have solved using the following steps: $a_i = sqrt(B/4\lambda_i)$ and then I am getting $x = v_i*a_i$ as 4 x 1 vector. However, I still don't find $x^HAx$ close to $B$. Any further comments on this?

Comment: What does it mean "close to $B$"? The expression $x^HAx$ equals to $B$.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: I have noticed that if $A$ is rank 4 positive definite, the method that you have mentioned gives $x$ such that $x^HAx = B$. However if $A$ is rank 1 positive definite, I obtain $x$ that doesn't satisfy $x^HAx = B$. Is there some other method to solve this problem in case A is rank 1 matrix?

Comment: I don't understand. First, a rank 1 matrix cannot be positive definite, only positive semidefinite. Second, the method works even if $A$ is only positive semidefinite. For example, if $\mathrm{rank} \, A = 1$ and $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$, then you can let $a_1,a_2,a_3$ be arbitrary scalars and you get an equation for $a_4$ which is $|a_4|^2 = \frac{B}{\lambda_4}$.